# Is it possible to disable a Spring Boot datasource configuration based on unavailability of a connection to a DB

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration

We have an application that uses several data sources.  A DB underlying one of those data sources is down at the moment: `IOError.  Network adapter couldn't establish the connection` & `Socket read timed out`.

Is there an annotation (or other means) of configuring Spring Boot such that it bypasses the culprit data source and still starts up: the DB is not essential in current development work. `spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true` doesn't seem to work.  This is Spring 2.2.2.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

using multiple datasource, so when your apps fail at start up your apps still work, i mean using memory db / sqlite to handle fail at connection error...